# MonoTouch and localizations in uploaded binary

Tags: localization, xamarin.ios

After uploading my binary to the appstore I went to the Binary Details page and discovered that it only states one language?

```
Localizations :     ( "en" )
```

In the last release it looked like

```
Localizations :     ( "en", "sv" )
```

I did change target from iOS 6.1 to iOS 5.

The question is, will this matter? The app seems to work fine anyhow?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself just after posting the question.

The .strings files in en.lproj and sv.lproj has to be set as content. They were set as bundled resource.